# how getInstance method works

Tags: joomla-3.x

I was going through codes of application, what document is and it has method getInstance method

```
public static function getInstance($client, $config = array(), $prefix = 'J')
{
    return JApplicationCms::getInstance($client);
}
```

Then went to JapplicationCms class that wasn't there i managed to find class
CMSApplication
it has definition

```
public static function getInstance($name = null)
{
    if (empty(static::$instances[$name]))
    {
        // Create a CMSApplication object.
        $classname = '\JApplication' . ucfirst($name);

        if (!class_exists($classname))
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException(\JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_APPLICATION_LOAD', $name), 500);
        }

        static::$instances[$name] = new $classname;
    }

    return static::$instances[$name];
}
```

Here in this function they are creating a classname. why they would create a class name, couldn't they have find class name by calling **class** creating a class name. 
they said always ask yourself how and why and i am stuck with loosing job no documentation any help appreciated. thank you

Comment: I believe the `$name` argument is used to determine the type of the application you want to get an instance of, such as `site`, `administrator`, `cli`, etc.: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/classmap.php#L24-L32

Comment: Thanyou for replying but why class name

Comment: What do you mean by "why class name"?

Comment: in document code they have tried accessing class JApplicationCms and there no no class called JApplicationCms. in JapplicationCms class they tried to create a class name and tried instantiating them. thank you for replying.

Comment: So if its alias class name. But they want cms application object then they could have simply done new __class__ . Why creating a variable classname which doesn't even exist and instantiating them.

Comment: So it is creating class for web, site, or cli which also has classname alias. Thank you.